# NSOutlineView source list style, view based, change font

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm using an NSOutlineView with source list style, and using the view based (rather than cell based) outline view.

I would like to be able to make some rows bold. However, my attempts to change the font (manually in IB, through code in viewForTableColumn:…, or through the Font Bold binding) have so far been ignored.

From [this message](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/316649-why-can-i-change-the-font-used-by-an-nstextfield.html), it appears that this is because the source list style for NSOutlineView takes over managing the text field's appearance:

> I'm guessing that you've hooked up your text field to the textField outlet of the NSTableCellView? If so, I think you might be running into NSTableView's automatic management of appearance for source lists.
>
> Try disconnecting the text field from the textField outlet and see if your custom font sticks.

If I disconnect the textField outlet, the appearance does come under my control, and my emboldening works.

However, now I can't get it to look like the automatic one. By which I mean, when NSOutlineView was managing the text field's appearance, the font was bold and gained a drop shadow when any item was selected, but when I'm managing it manually this is not the case.

Can anyone answer either of these questions:

1. How can I get the Font Bold binding to work when NSOutlineView is managing the appearance of my text field
2. If I don't have NSOutlineView manage the appearance of my text field, how can I make it look and behave like it would if I did have it manage it?

Comment: Any insights gained since the questions was asked? I have a similar problem :(

Comment: I think I gave up and used an icon rather than changing the font. It might be possible, but I never found out how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

`NSTableCellView` manages the appearance of it's `textField` outlet by setting the `backgroundStyle` property on cells of contained controls. Setting this to `NSBackgroundStyleDark` triggers a special path in `NSTextFieldCell` which essentially sets an `attributedStringValue`, changing the text color and adding an shadow via `NSShadowAttributeName`.

What you could do is two things:

- Set the `backgroundStyle` on your own in a custom row or cell view subclass.
- Use a custom `NSTextFieldCell` in the cell's text field and change the behavior/drawing.

We did the latter since we needed a different look for a themed (differently colored) table view. The most convenient (albeit surely not most efficient) location we found for this was to override `- drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` and modify the cell's attributed string before calling super, restoring the original afterwards:

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSAttributedString *originalString = self.attributedStringValue;

    // Customize string as you like
    if (/* whatever */)
        [self setAttributedStringValue: /* some string */];

    // Regular drawing
    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];

    // Reset string
    if (self.attributedStringValue != originalString)
        self.attributedStringValue = originalString;
}
```

In the hope this may help others in similar situations.

Comment: Thanks for that. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have missed anything in your question but changing the font using the following works for me. `ReminderTableCellView` is just a subclass of NSTableCellView with an additional dateField added.

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {
    //LOG(@"viewForTableColumn called");
    // For the groups, we just return a regular text view.
    if ([_topLevelItems containsObject:item]) {
        //LOG(@" top level");
        NSTableCellView *result = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
        // Uppercase the string value, but don't set anything else. NSOutlineView automatically applies attributes as necessary
        NSString *value = [item uppercaseString];
        [result.textField setStringValue:value];
        //[result.textField setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont smallSystemFontSize]]];
        return result;
    } else  {
        //LOG(@" menu item");
        // The cell is setup in IB. The textField and imageView outlets are properly setup.
        // Special attributes are automatically applied by NSTableView/NSOutlineView for the source list
        ReminderTableCellView *result = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
        if ([item isKindOfClass:[OSTreeNode class]]) {
            [result.textField setFont:[NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
            result.textField.stringValue = [item displayName];
            result.dateField.stringValue = [item nextReminderDateAsString];
        }
        else
            result.textField.stringValue = [item description];
        if (_loading)
            result.textField.textColor = [NSColor grayColor];
        else
            result.textField.textColor = [NSColor textColor];
        NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"ReminderMenuIcon.png"];
        [image setSize:NSMakeSize(16,16)];
        [result.imageView setImage:image];
        //[result.imageView setImage:nil];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Resulting view is shown below.  Note this is is an NSOutlineView with Source Listing option selected but I can't see why this would'nt work for a normal outlineView.

[image]